# Pandas DataFrame Groupby two columns and add column for moving average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to group using multiple columns and then add a calculated column (mean) based on the grouping. Can someone give me a hand?

I have tried the grouping and it works fine, but adding the calculated (rolling mean) column is proving to be a hustle

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], list('AAAAAAAABBBBBBBB'), ['RED','BLUE','GREEN','YELLOW','RED','BLUE','GREEN','YELLOW','RED','BLUE','GREEN','YELLOW','RED','BLUE','GREEN','YELLOW'], ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2'],[100,112,99,120,105,114,100,150,200,134,167,150,134,189,172,179]]).T
df.columns = ['id','Station','Train','month_code','total']
df2 = df.groupby(['Station','Train','month_code','total']).size().reset_index().groupby(['Station','Train','month_code'])['total'].max()
```

Looking at getting an outcome similar to this below

```
Station  Train   month_code total   average
A   BLUE        1       112 
                2       114       113
    GREEN       1       99        106.5
                2       100       99.5
    RED         1       100       100
                2       105       102.5
    YELLOW      1       120       112.5
                2       150       135
B   BLUE        1       134       142
                2       189       161.5
    GREEN       1       167       178
                2       172       169.5
    RED         1       200       186
                2       134       167
    YELLOW      1       150       142
                2       179       164.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you change your initial `groupby` to keep the column name `'total'`.

```
df3 = df.groupby(['Station','Train','month_code']).sum()

>>> df3.head()
                          id  total
Station Train month_code           
A       BLUE  1            2    112
              2            6    114
        GREEN 1            3     99
              2            7    100
        RED   1            1    100
```

Then do a rolling mean on the `total` column.

```
df3['average'] = df3['total'].rolling(2).mean()

>>> df3.head()
                          id  total  average
Station Train month_code                    
A       BLUE  1            2    112      NaN
              2            6    114    113.0
        GREEN 1            3     99    106.5
              2            7    100     99.5
        RED   1            1    100    100.0
```

You can then still remove the id column if you don't want it.